# Related Products extend with Cross sell products - Magento 2.4

Tags: magento2, related-products, cross-sells

We use the following method to group related products based on their category: https://bitbucket.org/magstaging/groupedrelatedproduct/src/master/

Works perfect, thanks to Herve, but we want to extend this code by also adding the cross sell items on the product page.

So what we want to is to display cross sell products on the product page in the same way, when they exists. Best solution would be to use the same template file for both. So that we can check if related or otherwise cross sell exists.

How can we achieve that?

Comment: What have you tried? Are you stuck on a specific part?

Answer (score 1):

the template and layout are the only files from the modules that you need to modify:

- the layout file currently only mentions `related` reference and it needs on top to mention either `product.info.upsell` or `checkout.cart.crosssell`. My advice is to use upsell on product page instead of cross sells as cross sells is for cart page?
- then, the template file can be modified and the modification may come from the core file `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/list/items.phtml`

the lines below are what you should focus onto:

```
case 'upsell':
        /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell $block */
        if ($exist = count($block->getItemCollection()->getItems())) {
            $type = 'upsell';
            $class = $type;

            $image = 'upsell_products_list';
            $title = __('We found other products you might like!');
            $items = $block->getItemCollection()->getItems();
            $limit = $block->getItemLimit('upsell');
            $shuffle = 0;
            $isWeightedRandom = 0;

            $showAddTo = false;
            $showCart = false;
            $templateType = null;
            $description = false;
            $canItemsAddToCart = false;
        }
        break;    
case 'crosssell-rule':
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell $block */
            if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
                $type = 'crosssell';
                $class = $type;
    
                $image = 'cart_cross_sell_products';
                $title = __('More Choices:');
                $items = $block->getItemCollection();
    
                $showAddTo = true;
                $showCart = true;
                $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
                $description = false;
                $canItemsAddToCart = false;
            }
            break;
    
        case 'crosssell':
            /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell $block */
            if ($exist = count($block->getItems())) {
                $type = 'crosssell';
                $class = $type;
    
                $image = 'cart_cross_sell_products';
                $title = __('More Choices:');
                $items = $block->getItems();
    
                $showAddTo = true;
                $showCart = true;
                $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
                $description = false;
                $canItemsAddToCart = false;
            }
            break;
```

these blocks may need to be part of your custom list.phtml template

Comment: Thanks Herve! How exactly should this layout file look like, to also implement upsell?